# Not able to push data to Kafka topic from different Machine

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am very new to Kafka.

I am trying to push data to kafka topic which is running in `172.11.22.12:9092` server. If I will run producer program in the same server (`172.11.22.12`) I'm able to push to the kafka topic and I can see in the consumer console also. If I am running in windows machine it is not pushing to the topic. Producer program is as follows:

```
 public class SimpleKafkaProducer {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
             props.put("bootstrap.servers", "172.11.22.12:9092");
             props.put("acks", "all");
             props.put("retries", 0);
             props.put("batch.size", 16384);
             props.put("linger.ms", 1);
             props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
             props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
             props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

             org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(props);
             for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));

             producer.close();

        }

    }
```

Log is as follows

```
14:46:47.662 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(172.11.22.12, 9092)], partitions = [])
14:46:47.771 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Sender - Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
14:46:47.771 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - Kafka producer started
14:46:47.773 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:47.773 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Init connection to node -1 for sending metadata request in the next iteration
14:46:47.773 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at 172.11.22.12:9092.
14:46:47.776 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:47.876 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:47.977 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.077 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.177 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.277 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.378 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.478 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.578 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.678 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.778 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.780 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - Error in I/O with /172.11.22.12
14:46:48.781 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Node -1 disconnected.
14:46:48.879 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.879 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Init connection to node -1 for sending metadata request in the next iteration
14:46:48.879 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at 172.11.22.12:9092.
14:46:48.879 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:48.979 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.079 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.179 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.280 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.380 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.480 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.580 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.680 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.781 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.881 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
14:46:49.884 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - Error in I/O with /172.11.22.12
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am using apache kafka 0.10.0.0 version

Comment: Resolved by changing the configuration **advertised.listeners**  of server.properties.

Comment: Hi, similar situation and same problem. Please guide, you have your kafka broker only at "Machine 172.11.22.12" right? and you only added the line "advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://137.226.58.50:9092" to your "server.properties on 172.11.22.12"? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the producer before closing it as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
             props.put("bootstrap.servers", "172.11.22.12:9092");
             props.put("acks", "all");
             props.put("retries", 0);
             props.put("batch.size", 16384);
             props.put("linger.ms", 1);
             props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
             props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
             props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

             org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(props);
             for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));

             producer.flush();
             producer.close();

        }
```